Can't update DE in Audience Builder OR update using query
I have a data extension that is mostly Boolean fields (null, true, false). the setup is this:



subKey
Row1
Row2
Row3




123

False



456
True





The fields are updated through a very complex cloudpage set up as a preferences center. That's working GREAT. HOWEVER, I was trying to manually update one of the fields in the Audience builder, and it gave me an error:

I then tried to use Query Studio to update it using a simple UPDATE prefDE SET Row3 = 'True' WHERE subKey = '123' - this gave me an error that said only SELECT statements are allowed. I haven't been able to figure out a way of getting an UPDATE function into a SELECT, and using another DE to update single fields at a time feels needlessly complicated.
There's no active Journey using the data extension, so I'm not sure why I can't update fields in any way. I am able to ADD rows and update those fields, but if I need to manually update a current field, it's not letting me.
Any advice?

Yes, SFMC only support SELECT statements  https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-basics/... the community need more details/actual fields,datatypes, length to help... alternatively you can try to export, make necessary modification and import back to ur DE... make sure to take backup

I think I narrowed it down to a different error, where there was email field that was populated with the subscriber key that wasn't an email address - initially I had no use for the field, so I left it, but as soon as I changed that, it was letting me manually update it. I am a little bummed that we can't use a Query to do this simple update in SFMC, but SFMC has a lot of limitations, so I shouldn't be surprised. Thank you for taking the time to put in the comment.

You need to use a SQL query activity in Automation Studio set to Update your data extension. Then run a select query to select your records needed and it will work, you can't use Query Studio, this just pulls a view of records from Data Extensions. You can also use the REST API to add records to a Data Extension via POSTMAN.
